# Apps Script URLFetchApp timeout too early

Tags: google-apps-script

I am running a routine to fetch some URLs and I noticed a few were timing out even though they load fine on a browser. The timeout happens after just 3 seconds which seems very odd to me. Is this a bug in google or could it be something wrongly configured on the site?

Here is an example:

```
function testFetch(){
  Logger.log(UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://mscoursing.com/').getContentText()) 
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a bug. Have you experienced this in other URLs or just this one? If there are more, could you provide some of those URLs? You could create an issue in Google Issue Tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/components/191640), or I can do it for you. There was a [similar issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36761961), but apparently it got fixed.

Comment: Ok I will investigate and file a bug report. Thanks for confirming I was not going crazy.